# ERROR: pull access denied for bookroom, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

Tags: spring, docker, docker-compose, jhipster

I have googled around and can't find a specific solution to mine. I have followed the instructions from [Lynda's JHipster: Build and Deploy microservices - tutorial](https://www.lynda.com/Spring-tutorials/JHipster-Build-Deploy-Spring-Boot-Microservices/624352-2.html) and I'm stuck at getting started with Docker at step 9 (3rd video). EVERYTHING IS RAN ON LOCAL HOST.

when running command:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

it throws:

```
ERROR: pull access denied for bookroom, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

I cd into my bookroom folder which has the microservice application bookroom and run

```
docker login
```

enter my docker ID credentials, try again in docker-compose folder command

```
docker-compose up -d
```

throws the same error again.

I did such a dramatic thing as such that I deleted my docker-compose folder and bookroom folder and redid the those stuff but still the same error is thrown.

I ran command in docker-compose:

```
docker login bookroom
```

entered my Docker ID credentials but gives

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://bookroom/v2/: Service Unavailable
```

I figured that means that the API has to be running in order to be validated. I builded the api and run the whole application and tried again but same error. pls note, everything is ran on local host. I think that's invalid url and I have no idea where that came from.

I also tried to get into my docker config files to see what's going on but whatsoever commands I put like

```
docker config inspect
docker config insepct --prettify
```

and throws the docker --help instead. Apologiez to docker gurus cringing, I'm new to docker. I tried to google for examples of those kinds of commands because it's asking for something like (and I can't figure out what it's precisely asking for :( ):

```
Usage: docker config inspect [OPTIONS] CONFIG [CONFIG...]
```

If someone would be so kind and give me advices what I should check into in order to solve this. 
Is the url https://bookroom/v2/ somehow wrongly configured? Should I change it? 
If so, how do I do it?
What command should I run in order view config files?

Loads of thanks if you read this far and is willing to help me.

[how my directory looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxdU2.png)

Comment: Did you build the bookroom docker image locally yet? http://www.jhipster.tech/docker-compose/

Comment: @JonRuddell I entered the command
 
     ./gradlew -Pprod bootRepackage buildDocker

in the bookroom folder.

Comment: Holy flowers, I think it's that! I forgot to build the image to bookroom after reinstalling it *facepalm*. I entered the command above to all microservice folders just to make sure that they are on the same level. Then the command docker-compose up -d went through. Thanks a lot man @JonRuddell. This made my day.